# Simple Hackable URL implementation for ASP.NET (3.5)

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a good sample project, or web site reference, which gives a simple easy to understand overview of URL Rewriting and making Hackable URLs.

I've read a good amount about the concept, but I'm specifically looking for a good implementation example for a programmer to use to get started.

This is specifically for .NET 3.5, so samples of that are perfect!

EDIT: Now that ASP.NET 4.0 is out, this issue is moot, because the URL routing mechanism is excellent and awesome.  I use it in all of my ASP.NET apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you mean for webforms, if so check out this post by phil haack
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx

If you meant asp.net MVC, check this out http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-399.aspx or any of the videos at www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net Routing (not rewriting) is the way to go. Two good post about the subject for starters:

http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx
http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0):

After reading these very helpful responses, and spending a fair amount of time researching this topic, and working on code samples with framework 3.5 sp1, I have found myself  successful.

To me, the best approach was to first implement this super simple example, and play with it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx
Next I found this excellent and simple example which extended the first example, and added support for parameters.  This example was simple and excellent:

http://bbits.co.uk/blog/archive/2008/05/19/using-asp.net-routing-independent-of-mvc---passing-parameters-to.aspx

I hope this helps everyone else looking at this topic; there seems to be considerable interest in this, even for developers who don't plan to use MVC.